# JS: How would a setTimeout in a promise chain work?

Tags: javascript

Would the following code wait for "A" to be logged before proceeding to the next `then()`?  I seem to reliably get back "A" logged before "B", even though it has a longer timeout specified.

```
     .then((response) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("A");
        }, 1000)
        this.doSomething();
    }).then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("B");
        },  800)
    })
```

Comment: it works just like it does anywhere else - i.e. asynchronously - so code after it doesn't wait for the timeout to happen - so your code calls doSomething, logs B then logs A - can't see how A would be logged before B - unless the code you actually use is a little different to what you've posted of course - that `this.doSomething()` as is shouldn't change anything ... so, what does `this.doSomething()` do?

Comment: @JaromandaX makes an API call to the server to fetch a lot of customer data

Comment: ok, is it an asynchronous API call? does the function return a Promise? does your actual code `return this.doSoemthing()` - because the details are important, as is, the code can NOT log A before B - unless the (non asynchronous) code in doSomething takes over 200ms - is there some heavy calculation happening in that code before the API request happens? or, as I suggested, is the API request being made synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` is non-blocking, so code always immediately proceeds and the stuff inside the timeout will happen sometime later. So in your case:

```js
     .then((response) => {
        // The timeout is *set* immediately without blocking
        setTimeout(() => {
            // This happens about a second from now
            console.log("A");
        }, 1000)
        // This happens immediately after *setting* the timeout.
        // The stuff inside that timeout happens *later*
        this.doSomething();
    }).then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("B");
        },  800)
    })
```

If you want to add timeouts to the chain you'll need something that uses a promise. For example:

```js
function wait (seconds){
  // This promise will resolve after the number of seconds specified
  return new Promise(res=>{
    setTimeout(res,seconds*1000);
  });
}
```

How you'd fit that in the logic chain depends on what you're trying to do. Definitely check out [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) if you're doing stuff with promises. It makes everything easier!

Comment: of course, this doesn't explain why A is logged before B :p